# Replace HTML tag content using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex, replace

I want to encrypt the text content of an HTML Document without changing its layout. The content is stored in pairs of tag , like this : < span style...>text_to_get< /span>. My idea is using Regex to retrieve (1) and to replace each text part with the encrypted text (2). I complete step (1) but have trouble at step (2) . Here is the code I'm working on :

```
private string encryptSpanContent(string text, string passPhrase, string salt, string  hash, int iteration, string initialVector, int keySize)        
{            
        string resultText = text;
        string pattern = "<span style=(?<style>.*?)>(?<content>.*?)</span>";   
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(resultText);          
        foreach (Match match in matches)    
        {                
            string replaceWith = "<span style=" + match.Groups["style"] + ">" + AESEncryption.Encrypt(match.Groups["content"].Value, passPhrase, salt, hash, iteration, initialVector, keySize) + "</span>";                
            resultText = regex.Replace(resultText, replaceWith);
        }
        return resultText;
}
```

Is this the wrong line (that makes all the texts replaced by the last replaceWith value) ?

```
            resultText = regex.Replace(resultText, replaceWith);
```

Can anybody help me to fix this ?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3):

It's recommended that you use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) if you're going to work with HTML, since you might run into issues with regex, especially on nested tags or malformed HTML.

Assuming your HTML is well-formed and you decide to use a regex, you should use the [`Regex.Replace` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) that accepts a `MatchEvaluator` to replace all occurrences.

Try this approach:

```
string input = @"<div><span style=""color: #000;"">hello, world!</span></div>";
string pattern = @"(?<=<span style=""[^""]+"">)(?<content>.+?)(?=</span>)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,
    m => AESEncryption.Encrypt(m.Groups["content"].Value, passPhrase, salt, hash, iteration, initialVector, keySize));
```

Here I use a lambada expression for the `MatchEvaluator` and refer to the "content" group as shown above. I also use look-arounds for the `span` tags to avoid having to include them in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Oh, and how can I write these lines in Java ? I found out that regex in Java is "worse" than it is in C# .
`String text = Text;
        String pattern = "<span style=(?<style>.*?)>(?<content>.*?)</span>";
        text = Regex.Replace(text, pattern,
                                   m => "<span style=" + m.Groups["style"] + ">" + Decrypt(m.Groups["content"].Value, PassPhrase, Salt, Hash, Iterations, InitialVector, KeySize) + "</span>");
        return text;`

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple solution for replacing HTML Tags

```
string ReplaceBreaks(string value)
{
    return Regex.Replace(value, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: While this is a roughly correct way of matching HTML tags, it will not replace each different tag with a specific string, essentially you will collapse all your tags to one type, losing important information.